# Get current user group name

Tags: 2013, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, active-directory

I am trying to get current user group name when the member is added via Active Directory in SharePoint 2013 using Rest/jQuery. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to use "currentUser" api to get current user id,then try use "GetUserById" function to list all groups.

```
function getCurrentUser()   
{  
getUserWebPermissionREST();  
$.ajax({  
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/CurrentUser",  
method: "GET",  
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
success: function (data)  
{  
getCurrentUserGroupColl(data.d.Id);  
},  
error: function (data)   
{  
failure(data);  
}  
});  
}  
function getCurrentUserGroupColl(UserID)   
{  
$.ajax  
({  
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + UserID + ")/Groups",  
method: "GET",  
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
success: function (data) {  
/* get all group's title of current user. */  
var results = data.d.results; var InnrHtmlgrp = "  
    <ul>";  
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)   
{  
InnrHtmlgrp += "  
        <li>" + results[i].Title + "</li>";  
}  
$("#Group").append(InnrHtmlgrp + "  
    </ul>");  
}  
});  
}
```

[https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36658.using-sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-group-collection-through-rest-api.aspx](http://check%20this%20link)

Answer (score 0):

```
var grp = new SPAPI_UserGroup("https://Site Url"); // pass site url

sLoginUserName1 = "test@test.com";   // email id of the user which is rendering in site

var ug = grp.getGroupCollectionFromUser(sLoginUserName1);

var rows = ug.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Group');

for (var i=0; i< rows.length; i++){

alert(rows[i].getAttribute('Name'));

}
```